# Send additional data to Java server-side using Dojo file upload client-side

Tags: java, file-upload, dojo

I need to send additional data to the server side while uploading files with dojo. How do I do that?

I'm using the upload method of the dojo file uploader. I want to dynamically pass an additional variable for file destination on the server side.

My JavaScript code:

```js
function(Uploader, FileList, dom, on, Carousel, ContentPane, SwapView) {
    dojo.ready(function() {
        var form = dojo.byId("myForm");              
        var uploaderDIV = dojo.byId("uploader");

      up = new Uploader({
          label: 'Attach Files',
          multiple: true,
          showInput: 'before',
          name : 'uploadedfiles[]',
          url: '/TestServer/rest-services/submitForm',
      }).placeAt(uploaderDIV);
```

And my server side code:

```js
@Path("/submitForm")
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) {

    String fileName = "";

    Map<String, List<InputPart>> formParts = input.getFormDataMap();
```

Comment: Generally `url: '/TestServer/rest-services/submitForm?whatever=you+want`

Comment: How do I read "whatever" on the server side? I'm fairly new to web programming.

Comment: On the *server*?  Depends upon your server-side language.  If in PHP, you could do `$_GET['whatever']`.  This approach is not robust, but it gets the job done.

Comment: I'm using Java on the server side

Comment: You're out of my depth with Java.  I've edited your question to maybe get more attention from folks with that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Apache FileUpload here, as it will *greatly* simplify your life.  In my implementations I have set up a servlet mapped to the upload URL and handled the request in a `doPost` method:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Piggybacking on the information provided by bishop directly in response to your question, you can attach URL parameters using the ? and & characters (i.e. ?one=one&two=two).  On the server side you'll need to read those URL parameters from the request:

```
String one = request.getParameter("one");
String two = request.getParameter("two");
```

Comment: I used url parameters and file uploader url can be dynamically set. up.set("url", "/TestServer/rest-services/submitForm?paramname=paramvalue"); and used @QueryParam to parse it in the java side. Thanks for your help.